# Pandas extract row in range

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas tables:

```
Table1
PosA    PosB    PosC
1       100     110
1       300     350
4       100     120

Table2
PosA   PosD
1      105
2      305
4      115
5      308
```

I want to extract all information from `Table1`, if `PosD` in Table2 is in range `PosB` and `PosC` AND `PosA` of `Table1` and `Table2` match extactly.

So the correct output is:

```
PosA   PosB   PosC   PosD
1      100    110    105
4      100    120    115
```

How to merge this two tables, according this rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.merge(table1, table2)
df[df['PosD'].between(df['PosB'], df['PosC'])]
```

Output:

```
    PosA    PosB    PosC    PosD
0    1      100     110     105
2    4      100     120     115
```

Answer (score 2):

Here df1 is your Table1 and df2 is your Table 2

```
import pandas as pd
```

Firstly make use of `reindex()` method in 'df1' so as to make its length equal to 'df2':-

```
df1=df1.reindex(df2.index)
```

then check your condition:-

```
mask=(df2['PosD'].between(df1['PosB'],df1['PosC'])) & (df2['PosA']==df1['PosA'])
```

And now merge them by using `merge()` method in `pandas` and pass the `mask` in `df1` inside `merge()` method:-

```
result=pd.merge(df1[mask],df2,on='PosA').astype(int)
```

Now if you print `**result**` then you will get your expected output:-

```
    PosA    PosB    PosC    PosD
0   1       100     110     105
1   4       100     120     115
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting a ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects error. Probably because the number of rows of the two tables are not identical?

Comment: Yes it was because of no. of rows in both dataframes are different

Comment: I edit my example, sorry it was a bad choice.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your question kindly have a look.........btw if this answer helped you then feel free to accept this answer :)